# How to solve GeeksForGeeks Divisible by 3 without running the program

Tags: calculus, algorithms

Can someone please explain to me how to calculate the value of "d" without running the program? This is taken from GeeksForGeeks website.

```
int d=0;
for(int i=0;i<31;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<31;j++)
        for(int k=0;k<31;k++) {
          if (((i+j+k) % 3)==0) {
              d=d+1;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a solution someone posted for the problem but, I do not understand how they got this. :(

Set 1 = { 3x | x in (1,10) }

Set 2 = { 3x + 1 | x in (0,10) }

Set 3 = { 3x + 2 | x in (0,9) }

Set containing all numbers from set 1 = 10*10*10 = 1000

Set containing 1 number each from set 1, set 2 and set 3 = 10*11*10*3! = 6600

Set containing numbers from set 2 only = 11*11*11 = 1331

Set containing numbers from set 3 only = 10*10*10 = 1000

Net = 9331

Comment: Choosing to make it go to 30 instead of 29 makes this problem unnecessarily harder.

Comment: @DanielV it makes it harder alright, but unnecessarily? If the purpose of the problem is to be challenging, making it harder may well be necessary in itself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh I assumed it was for teaching purposes.  If it is a challenge then yeah you are right.

Comment: It helps when you ask questions to say what part confused you, and how much you do understand.  It is not like we can answer every question starting at 1+1=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about if the program was this instead:

```
int[3][3][3] count;
// initialize count to zero
memset(count, 0, sizeof(count));

for(int i=0;i<31;i++)
for(int j=0;j<31;j++)
for(int k=0;k<31;k++) {
  count[i%3][j%3][k%3] += 1;
}
```

Now, what is the value of $\text{count}[x][y][z]$ ?  For example, $\text{count}[0][1][2] = 1100$ tells us that $i \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ and $j \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $k \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ exactly $1100$ times.  The value of $\text{count}[x][y][z]$ can be calculated easily without running the program.

- There are $11$ values that are divisible by $3$ in $[0 \dots 30]$: $\quad$ $0, 3, 6, \dots 30$
- There are $10$ values that are 1 more than a multiple of $3$: $\quad$ $1, 4, 7, \dots 28$
- There are $10$ values that are 2 more than a multiple of $3$: $\quad$ $2, 5, 8, \dots 29$

So $\text{count}[0][0][0]$ is just $11 \times 11 \times 11$, and $\text{count}[1][0][2]$ is just $10 \times 11 \times 10$, etc.

So if you want to count the number of times $i + j + k \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, it is just the number of times $\text{count}[x][y][z]$ is incremented when $x + y + z \equiv 0 \pmod 3$.  That occurs when

- $x = y = z = 0$, or $\text{count}[0][0][0]$ times, or $11^3$ times
- $x = y = z = 1$, or $\text{count}[1][1][1]$ times, or $10^3$ times
- $x = y = z = 2$, or $\text{count}[2][2][2]$ times, or $10^3$ times
- $x = 0, y = 1, z = 2$, or one of the $3!$ ways $x, y, z$ can be assigned the values $0, 1, 2$, so $3! \times 11 \times 10 \times 10$.

So altogether it is $11^3 + 10^3 + 10^3 + 3!\times 11 \times 10 \times 10 = 9931$.

Comment: Amazing explanation, thank you!

Comment: @JonTan Thank you.  Don't forget to upvote Hennings answer if you found his answer useful.  And if either answer answered your question, choose the one that helped you the most and mark it as the answer so the question will be closed.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is my first time posting on math stackexchange and my points from stackoverflow don't carry over so I cannot upvote either of your answers at the moment. ;(

Answer (score 1):

A faster way to count is to divide the solutions into three classes:

- $k\ne 0$. For each combination of $i$ and $j$ there is exactly $10$ values of $k$ between $1$ and $30$ that makes the sum a multiple of $3$. This gives $31\cdot 31\cdot 10$ combinations.
- $k=0, j\ne 0$. For each $i$ there is exactly $10$ values of $j$ between $1$ and $30$ that makes the sum a multiple of $3$. This gives $31\cdot 10$ combinations.
- $k=0, j=0$. There are $11$ values of $i$ that are multiples of $3$.

So,
$$ 31\cdot31\cdot10 + 31\cdot10 + 11 = 9931 $$

Comment: Wow, I did not think of this at all. Thank you!

Comment: Hello Henning sir, sir can you please help me out in this problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502590/question-on-asymptotic-function?noredirect=1#comment5168859_2502590 , i will make sure that i will delete this comment later .I am in desperate need of this answer ..unable to move forward