# Solving recurrence equation $T(n)=T(n/2)+ \log n$ with $T(1)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

> Solve Recurrence Equation:
>
> $$T(n)=T(n/2)+ \log n\qquad T(1)=1$$

*My approach:*

$T(\frac{n}{2})=T(\frac{n}{4})+ \log \frac{n}{2}$

$T(\frac{n}{4})=T(\frac{n}{8})+ \log \frac{n}{4}$

$\text{Hence},$

$T(n)=T(\frac{n}{8})+ \log \frac{n}{4}+\log \frac{n}{2}+\log n$

$T(n)=\log \frac{n}{2^{k}}+\log \frac{n}{2^{k-1}}+....+\log \frac{n}{2}+\log n$

$\text{Using base case , i got k=log n}$

$\text{hence}$

$T(n)=\log (n \times \frac{n}{2} \times \frac{n}{2^2} \times...\times \frac{n}{2^{k-1}})$
I am stuck to move forward .
However i know it can be solved from other(by seeing/analysing the solution of this question already posted in this site)way -:

> $T(n)=\log n + \log \frac{n}{2} +\log \frac{n}{2^{2}}+....+\log \frac{n}{2^{k}}$

$T(n)=\log n +\log n -\log 2+\log n -\log 4+..\log n -\log 2^{k} (2^{k}=n)$

$T(n)=\log n -0 +\log n -1+\log n -2+..\log n -\log n $

$T(n)=\log n \times \log n -\log n \times \frac{(1+\log n)}{2}=\theta(\log ^2 n) $

Please help me out to move forward over this step

> $T(n)=\log (n \times \frac{n}{2} \times \frac{n}{2^2} \times...\times \frac{n}{2^{k-1}})$.

Comment: see the updated question

Comment: Why did you instantly accept a substandard answer?

Comment: @Did i am sorry sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stricto sensu, this recursion only defines $T(n)$ when $n$ is a power of $2$, thus, we might introduce $$x_k=T(2^k)$$ Then, $x_0=T(1)=1$ and, for every $k\geqslant1$, $$x_k=T(2^k)=T(2^{k-1})+\log2^k=x_{k-1}+\log2\cdot k$$ Iterating this, one gets trivially $$x_k=x_0+\log2\cdot(1+2+\cdots+k)=1+\frac{\log2}2\cdot k(k+1)$$ in particular $$T(2^k)=x_k=\Theta(k^2)=\Theta((\log 2^k)^2)$$ It is then customary in the field, **but quite nonrigorous**, to deduce from this rigorous result that $$T(n)=\Theta((\log n)^2)$$

Comment: thanks a lot sir

Comment: Did sir , sorry to comment here about other question, but i have no option left .I have doubt here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2502590/question-on-asymptotic-function?noredirect=1#comment5170768_2502590 but i am stuck at one point and unable to move forward.Please have a look , i will make sure that i willl delete this comment

Comment: Wait, but you HAVE received an answer over there, right?

Comment: sir , i am not getting the answer .Please give me atleast a hint to move forward . I used  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation to simplify somehow , but i am completely clueless to move forward .Please help sir  :)

Answer (score 0):

$$T(n)=\log (n \times \frac{n}{2} \times \frac{n}{2^2} \times...\times \frac{n}{2^{k-1}})$$

Rewrite this as $$T(n)=\log(\frac{n^k}{2^{\frac{k(k-1)}{2}}})$$

Notice that this is equivalent to $$k\log(n)-\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\cdot\log2$$

Can you now substitute the value of $k$ in this equation to see why this is $\theta(\log ^2 n)$?

Comment: This is rather odd, already the first identity $$T(n)=\log (n \times \frac{n}{2} \times \frac{n}{2^2} \times...\times \frac{n}{2^{k-1}})$$ is obviously wrong in general. Or are you considering some specific $(n,k)$? Please explain.

Comment: @Did Yes, you are correct in the sense that I am really restricting my focus to extremely special cases (a bad habit from thinking about algorithmic efficiency in contest programming). I'm also quite unhealthily claiming that it's easy to see why $T(n)$ is $\Theta((\log n)^2)$.  Your answer is more accurate and helpful.